# Can't i create study result for student

Tags: custom-fields

i doing customization CiviCRM,

My Charity working for Education(Donor, student, volunteer). One student have 1 study result/year.

example: student study 12 year then student have 12 study result.

Can't i do that. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question! You will need to provide a little more detail on what you are trying to achieve for us to be able to help you? And what version of CiviCRM are you using with what CMS?

Comment: i doing CiviCRM 5.29.1 for Wordpress 5.5.1 last version.hehe

Comment: My organization to small, i try customize CiviCRM for managerment my Donor, Volunteer, Student(1-12,university,vocational training). i see internet CiviCRM very strong for nonprofit. i try it. please help me. hehe

Comment: I understand that you try to customize but I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. So can you please eplain what it is you want to achieve? I have no idea what you mean when you say "one student have 1 study result/year, can I do that?". What is it you want to do or see with this result? Have you read the user guide (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/)? Have you tried a custom group with year/result for the student?

Comment: It will help if you spell out example eg

Comment: Pete - 71% - 2020 or

Comment: Eric - A+ or perhaps

Comment: Hai - 8.5 in 2020, 7.3 in 2019, 8.1 in 2018 etc

Comment: Hi  ErikH - CiviCooP, please see answer bellow, in comment i can't post image. hehe. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry. i explain now,hehe. i want customize Student profile in Contact.
Our students after each academic year will have 1 corresponding academic results.

For example: a student who studied for 10 years will have 10 different results.

- In 2019: student Hai have GPA:5.0 , study result: Pass
- In 2020: student Hai have GPA:6.0 , study result: Pass
- In 2021: student Hai have GPA:7.0 , study result: Pass.

When I customize student profile, I think it only saves 1 study result for 1 student in profile.
Currently I want a student to be able to save many study results(1 Student-many result).
When I open the student profile, I can see all of that student's academic results over the years.
Please see image attached. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom field set by going to your CiviCRM menu **Administer > Customised Data and screen > Custom Fields**. During the setup process remember to tick “**Does this Custom Field Set allow multiple records?**”

You can also choose “**Display style**” for how you want to see this result, as a tab or inline or table.  Depending on the option you choose, you will see the results within a contact record.

[image]

Comment: wow, i got it, thanks so much, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much,
i try follow up your susgestion.

[image]

[image]

i add study test tab & table, but when create new student, i not see it in form.hehe

Comment: what happens if you create New Student and then go back to look. do you see the Tab then?

Comment: also pls note. StackExchange is a Question and Answer format. Answers you enter which are not Answers will get marked down. You should edit your Original question to add more information.